# PHP Atom feeds are not showing

Tags: php, feed, atom-feed

I'm using PHP to generate feeds, which is working perfectly fine on my local development sandbox. Once I upload to the server, I get a blank page. I know the programming is correct, because it works fine on my local box. What do you think the problem might be? I'm not using any extra libraries, atleast I don't think so. I put on error reporting and received no issues. Any ideas?

Comment: What do your PHP error logs say?

Comment: Please post the code. We've got no way to diagnose the problem if you don't. Don't assume the programming is "correct"... code can fail when deployed (Specifically if the server is a different platform. Linux vs Windows)

Comment: +1 to ceejayoz. the "blank page" is usually due to errors being suppressed in production. The logs will detail anything gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are outputing the correct Content-type, also try to validate the feed using some third party online service. If you are really getting nothing check your server logs, there must be a silenced error.